# Strange behavior while using queue that contains pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, queue

I am trying to create a binary tree that when you try to add a new node to that, it adds the node to first position that is `nullptr`.

actually making a complete binary tree.

Look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class node{
private:
    char data;
    node* right;
    node* left;
public:
    node(char n){
        data = n;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    char getdata(){
        return data;
    }
friend class binTree;
};

class binTree{
private:
    node *root;
public:
    binTree(){
        root = nullptr;
    }
    binTree(node *root){
    this->root = root;
    }

    node* getRoot(){
    return this->root;
    }


    void addNode(char data){
        cout << "adding " << data << endl;

        if(root == nullptr) {
            root = new node(data);
            return;
        }


        queue<node*> Q;
        Q.push(root);
        node* toadd;
        while(true) {
            node* toadd = Q.front();
            Q.pop();
            Q.push(toadd->left);
            Q.push(toadd->right);

            if(toadd->left == nullptr)  break;
            if(toadd->right == nullptr) break;
        }

        if((toadd->left) == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "add data to the left of " << toadd -> data << endl;
            toadd->left = new node(data);
        } else if((toadd -> right) == nullptr){
            cout << "add data to the right of " << toadd -> data << endl;
            toadd->right = new node(data);
        } else {
            cout << "toadd left and right are not nullptr" << endl;
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    binTree bin;
    string s = "abcdefg";
    cout << s << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        bin.addNode(s[i]);
    }
}
```

when I run this code the output is:

```
abcdefg

adding a
adding b
toadd left and right are not nullptr
adding c
toadd left and right are not nullptr
adding d
toadd left and right are not nullptr
adding e
toadd left and right are not nullptr
adding f
toadd left and right are not nullptr
adding g
toadd left and right are not nullptr
```

the strange part is when printing "toadd left and right are not nullptr"
because there is a while(true) and the only exit conditions are:

```
            if(toadd->left == nullptr)  break;
            if(toadd->right == nullptr) break;
```

so one of these conditions were true that we could break the loop;
so we should enter one of `if` or `else if` part of the following code (after the while) but surprisingly we enter the `else` part and end of printing "toadd left and right are not nullptr".
can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've defined `toadd` twice, once before the loop and once inside. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: `-Werror=shadow` on gcc and clang avoids this category of error.